# Can't define active link color in custom Drupal theme

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, colors

I'm using the following code to print a two-level nested menu in my custom Drupal theme:

```
<?php
    print drupal_render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')));
?>
```

This works fine, and now I'm trying to edit the menu appearance in my style.css file using the following code.

```
a:link {color:#fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-size: 22px;}    
a:active {color: #93278f;}
a:visited {color:#fff;} 
a:hover {color: #93278f;}
```

The link, visited and hover color settings work fine, but the active link color does not work. Instead of the desired color #93278f the active links are just black. What do I have to do to make this work?

In the source I see that the code for an active menu item is e.g.

```
<li class="leaf active-trail"><a href="/drupal-7.22/?q=node/7" class="active-trail active-trail active-trail active">MENU ITEM</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Active is a CSS class, which is target with a "dot" in CSS (instead of the semi-colon you're using).

Change your CSS code to

```
a:link {color:#fff; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-size: 22px;}    
a.active {color: #93278f;}
a:visited {color:#fff;} 
a:hover {color: #93278f;}
```

and try again. Otherwise, it always good to have a look with Firebug to see what is overriding your CSS definitions.

Comment: The . point did not do anything, but using Firebug I was able to see that my css was overriden by the Drupal system.menus.css file. So thanks for the tip:)

Comment: Isn't there some sort of custom.css file which is loaded last into the page? That should be able to override all general styles.